# Error: `loc1@GLIBC_2.4' While cross compiling GLIBC for ARM

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling, glibc, gcc-warning

I have tried to cross compile GLIBC 2.25 for ARM arch

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
#arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0


git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout glibc-2.25
mkdir build
cd build
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export glibc_install="$(pwd)/install"
../configure --prefix "$glibc_install" --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --disable-werror
make
```

The error that I got is :

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/Desktop/glibc/misc'
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc regexp.c -c -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline  -O2 -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -fno-stack-protector -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition   -fPIC   -ftls-model=initial-exec   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE   -I../include -I/home/user/Desktop/glibc/build/misc  -I/home/user/Desktop/glibc/build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm  -I../sysdeps/arm/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/arm  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/arm/include -I../sysdeps/arm  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /home/user/Desktop/glibc/build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h  -DPIC -DSHARED     -o /home/user/Desktop/glibc/build/misc/regexp.os -MD -MP -MF /home/user/Desktop/glibc/build/misc/regexp.os.dt -MT /home/user/Desktop/glibc/build/misc/regexp.os
/tmp/ccNe3Uva.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccNe3Uva.s: Error: `loc1@GLIBC_2.4' can't be versioned to common symbol 'loc1'
/tmp/ccNe3Uva.s: Error: `loc2@GLIBC_2.4' can't be versioned to common symbol 'loc2'
/tmp/ccNe3Uva.s: Error: `locs@GLIBC_2.4' can't be versioned to common symbol 'locs'
make[2]: *** [../o-iterator.mk:9: /home/user/Desktop/glibc/build/misc/regexp.os] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Desktop/glibc/misc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:215: misc/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Desktop/glibc'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

How can I fix that?